# SQL Server view query generating too much temp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have been noticing when a month end job which basically queries a view is generating too much temp data. The database size is 50GB (in simple mode) and the view uses two tables which are not more than 2 GB. This is view given by some vendor and it is been running for a while until recently the job never finishes as it fills up the temp drive although we added 200GB

We not sure what `sys.sp_addextendedproperty` is used for in this view. Can anyone noticing any issue with this view for SQL Server 2012

## view sql

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LBJ_TAX_RPT_SUM_ALL]
AS
SELECT    ....
FROM         dbo.table_1 AS S INNER JOIN
                      dbo.table_2 AS T ON ....
GROUP BY  .....

GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-sdfscf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[41] 4[21] 2[33] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "S"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 114
               Right = 256
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "T"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 294
               Bottom = 114
               Right = 513
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 12
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'RPT_SUM_ALL'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=1 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'RPT_SUM_ALL'
GO
```

Comment: `sp_addextendedproperty` is irrelevant. All it tells you is that the builder of the view has dubious SQL skills because they built it in a designer window rather than writing a query. I suggest you remove all of the `sp_addextendedproperty` part and include all of the view definition. Then indicate how many records each table has, then press CTRL-L to get the query plan and post that.

Answer (score 2):

`'sys.sp_addextendedproperty'` (in this case) is adding meta data to describe how the query designer should display the query. This has zero impact on how the query executes. If you have a question as to why the query is filling up tempdb, you'll need to ask that by posting the T-SQL and preferably the execution plan.